# Direct output to another terminal session and restore prompt?

Tags: bash, terminal

I am directing terminal output from one terminal session to another. When the session receives the output, the prompt goes away. Pressing Enter, the prompt will return.

Any tips on how to automatically restore the prompt?

For example.

```bsh
# ttys001

$ echo -e 'Notice that the prompt is not restored\ntill after pressing Enter.' > /dev/ttys002
$
```

```bsh
# ttys002

$ Notice that the prompt is not restored
till after pressing Enter.
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - this is working as expected, you can't.

The prompt isn't actually "going away" - it's still there, waiting for a command. When you enter a command (or anything, really) into a terminal, pressing the key only sends that character as input, it doesn't actually cause that key to be displayed on the screen. The terminal immediately echoes it to the screen as output, so it seems like pressing a key causes the character to appear, but it's actually a two-way "conversation". Likewise, when you echo something from s001 to s002's terminal, you're simply echoing characters to that terminal's output, you're not actually interrupting anything or invalidating the prompt. You can see the practical effects by typing `ls` (or any other command) in s002 immediately after running the `echo` in s001 but before hitting enter in s002. Your prompt is still there, waiting for you, you just added some stuff to the screen.